# What's the proper plural for file extensions?

Tags: orthography, irregular-plurals

I have one .msi. Then I get another. Do I now have:

> two .msis

or

> two .msi's

or

> two '.msi's

or something else?

Comment: You could bypass this altogether and just say "two .msi **files**". Unless, of course, you have a word/character/space limit.

Comment: Are you asking about grammar or orthography? Grammar is what you say aloud and hear; orthography is what you write.

Comment: @tchrist I disagree with the close vote. They're similar but clearly not identical - a file extension is not necessarily an acronym. txt is short for 'text'. I can even create my own extensions however I want.

Comment: I'm interested in the conventions are for this, and agree with @Sarov that this question is distinct from the 'duplicate' – I still don't have an answer for this question from reading the  other

Comment: One approach could be to capitalize the extension: e.g. two .CSVs – though it's much less common these days to see capitalized extensions in the wild

Answer (score 5):

One easy way round it is to write

> two .msi files

which also makes it clear to anyone who doesn't know what .msi means.

Another solution is to use uppercase letters for the file extension:

> two MSIs
>   two .MSIs

Its best to avoid the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_(%22greengrocers'_apostrophes%22)).